# Complex SQL Statement with multiple IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

First let me show you example-records.

**Table: objekte**

```
+--------+----------+---------+------------+
| objid  | objidate | objmask | deletedate |
+--------+----------+---------+------------+
| 271136 | 54084960 | 4       | 0          |
| ...    | ...      | ...     | ...        |
+--------+----------+---------+------------+
```

**Table: objkeys**

```
+----------+--------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| parentid | okeyno |  okeyname  |              okeydata               |
+----------+--------+------------+-------------------------------------+
|  1511160 |      1 | BelegNr.   | 634685                              |
|  1511160 |      2 | BELEGARTBK | oU = Lieferschein ohne Unterschrift |
+----------+--------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

**Now, here's is what i have tried so far:**

```
SELECT * FROM objekte
WHERE objid IN (
            SELECT MIN(parentid) as parentid FROM objkeys
            WHERE okeyname = 'BelegNr.' 
            GROUP BY okeydata
            HAVING COUNT(okeydata) = 1
    ) AND objmask = '69' AND deletedate = '0' AND DATEADD(mi, objidate, '30.12.1899') >= DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())
```

**Expected output:**
I want to display all **objid** from table **objekte** (`objkeys.parentid = objekte.objid`) where there exists only one record for the `okeyname "Belegn"` where the `BELEGARTBK is "oU = Lieferschein ohne Unterschrift".`

In my SQL code I can show all the current objects who are "unique". But I can't filter by "BELEGARTBK" at the moment. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: I would advise to create a SQL fiddle with a lot more data that you have shown there. It is very unclear to me how much duplicate `okeyname` you can have for `BelegNr.` and `BELEGARTBK`  values. This database design doesnt look good

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not very clear what you ask, try with this nested query:

```
  SELECT parentid FROM objkeys
    WHERE okeyname = 'Belegn' and okeydata = 'Lieferschein ohne Unterschrift' 
    GROUP BY parentid 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```